# uicollectionview remove top padding

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is the entire view but it lives inside "view" (it is not UICollectionViewController). Adding a cell to this collection view shows it in the following order in storyboard:

[image: Storyboard View]

This is how it looks in the emulator:

[image: Emulator View]

I don't understand how to get rid of that view. All the insets are at zero in Storyboard Size Inspector for collection view. Just to be sure, I also have the following code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let layout = self.collectionViewProducts.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    let containerWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40.0
    let itemWidth = (containerWidth / 3.0)
    let itemHeight = (itemWidth / 0.75) + 30

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)

    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

How can I get rid of that top padding?

Comment: Have you tried adding self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero. Sorry for Swift 2.3 syntax

Comment: check my updated answer...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can fix top padding issue by considering one of the following method.

**Method 1**: Natural way to fix your problem by setting up your collectionView `dimensions` properly from `StoryBoard`.

[image]

**Method 2**: `**Updated**`

You can validate `collection frame` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

**Method 3**: You can `Adjust Scroll View Insets` from your `StoryBoard` `Attributes Inspector`.

[image]

**Method 4**: You can fix this issue programatically by adjusting CollectionView `contentInset`.

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: **Any Value**, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

**Output with top padding 5:**

[image]

**Output with top padding 44:**

[image]

**Output with top padding 64:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is one more way to resolve this issue and that is selecting collectionView -> scrollView Content Insets -> "Automatic" to "Never".

By default scrollView Content Insets value is Automatic. Please check the below image.

For more details check: UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior

[image]

Comment: A great solution

Answer (score 3):

I think because this viewController is embedded in a navigationController. Let select this viewController in the storyboard and uncheck **Adjust Scroll View Insets**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make your `Navigation Controller > NavigationBar` translucent by unchecking the **Translucent** check box in IB > Attribute Inspector, and it will work.

Comment: Struggled with this for way too long and this was the fix!

Answer (score 1):

After setting the content insets of `UICollectionView` to zero like below:

```
collectionView.contentInset = .zero
```

OR

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Just try this:

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the previously suggested approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and i fixed it with a way totally ridiculous solution.

My collectionView contained several sections which had no title & no item cells.

The top, bottom inset values of the section insets were 10 respectively. 
so each empty section charged height of 20 pixels.

I had 4 empty sections, and therefore, 80 top margins in the collection view.

Hope you check this as well if none of the above solutions works.