# Header View behind NavigationBar

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, transparent, navigationbar

I would like to do something like that:

[image: Test 1]

I tried to set a transparent background for the NavigationBar :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

}
```

However, there is a problem. When I launch the view, the HeaderView is not on the top (behind the navigation bar):

[image]

But if I scroll down, the HeaderView is going behind the NavigationBar, like that:

[image]

I would like to start like that when I launch the view. I don't understand why it's not the case, because all "top parameters" are equal to 0.

Here are my components :

[image]

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding/43025517#43025517

Comment: @Joe Thank you very much it's working !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this questions really helped me ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding/43025517#43025517