# How can i put my collection view under the navigation bar Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

in my app there is a image on top of the collectionview header and i need the collectionview under the nav bar [image: IT looks like this]

[image: but needs to be like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding/43025517#43025517

Answer (score 3):

Select the collection view, go to size inspector and set the content insets to never in the scroll view section

Comment: it may also be necessary to set `(self.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInsetReference = .fromContentInset`

Answer (score 0):

set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to true (it should be by default). You can do this in code or in the storyboard by selecting the view controller.

If that doesn't fix your issue you should adjust your autolayout constraints. if you can show how you have created the view layout I can guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `collectionView` constraints to the bottom of `topLayoutGuide` in your UIViewController:

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the collectionView top constraint to view top constraint, not the topLayoutGuide bottom (as topLayoutGuide bottom is the bottom of navigation bar in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Set the collection view's [contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior) to `.never`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790137/1672161)