# How to remove top space from Top of TableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my View controller i have 1 tableview with different Data.

Top Blue colour is View & bottom Blue colour is TabBar.

in Home Screen there's top View & in Trending screen i Hide it by changing it's constraint to 0.

1. Home and 2. Trending

When i scroll tableview to see new posts & when i click on Trending View i load new data in TableView & scroll tableview to top with the code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tblVW setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        [self.tblVW reloadData];
    });
```

but it will not move to top of tableview.

There's a space at top & when i touch tableview it will scroll to top.

Comment: check this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding/43025517#43025517

Answer (score 14):

In a **grouped tableview**,If you want to remove the default header in the top area, try setting:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0.1))
```

#### Grouped TableView:

[image: Grouped TableView]

#### Before:

[image: Before]

#### After:

[image: After]

Comment: Wow Working For me in Xcode 11 and iOS 13 thank you so much.

Comment: can you please tell me I did height 0 then it not work but when I did same as you do 0.1 height then it works why .?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using grouped tableview. Kindly make

```
self.tblVW.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0.01f)];
```

Even set height of tableview section header as 0.01f.

Comment: i return minimum height by return CGFLOAT_MIN;

Comment: Are you using grouped tableview? @Pankil. Can you please change it to 0.01f instead of CGFLOAT_MIN? i guess it should work.

Comment: yes, home tableview is grouped tableview & trending tableview is plain.

Comment: Set the tableheader view as the self.tblVW.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0.01f)]; for home tableview. it will remove the top space. 
.

Comment: For grouped tableview if you have observed settings app in iphone it has default space at the top. So to fix it we need to set tableheaderview with frame(0,0,0,0.01f) and even set section header height as 0.01f as 0.0f won't work in that case. Kindly check it at your end and let me know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Set Above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets .

add this line ViewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: I already unCheck it from Storyboard, but still i am facing this issue

Comment: when i scroll trending data to bottom and than i click on home, it will scroll to top. but when i am on home screen and click on trending tableview not scroll to top automatically.

Comment: try also this : tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this to scroll the table view to top

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tblVW.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0,inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)];
        [self.tblVW reloadData];
    });
```

instead of setting content offset.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, put this code inside the viewDidLoad() `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -35, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.setupTableView() 
}

func setupTableViews() {
   tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -35, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) 
}
```