# How to remove extra space in UICollectionView when scrolling to top with Status bar gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView the behavior is normal when I'm scrolling down and If I want to reach to top items using the scroll top top gesture from the status bar I get an extra space.

[Extra space in title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADfF6.png)

Here is a gif showing the [behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKZcX.gif):

I don't want that extra space.

I don't know if It's a property in the UICollectionView or in the same NavigationController.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you pinned collectionView with Top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint?

Comment: I have my CollectionView with my four constraints align to safe area

Comment: Have you tried with self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO ?in ViewDidLoad ??

Comment: Well my CollectionView is embedded in a ViewController and this ViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller and the Navigation Controller embedded in one of the tabs of a Tab bar controller: TabBar --> NavigationController --> ViewController --> CollectionViewController (as an element) I am using LargeTitles for the navigation bar.

Comment: "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO" It did not work @Mr.Ahtazaz

Comment: Please take a look at this... i Hope this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding

Comment: Let me know if it still not help you...

Comment: one of the solutions worked, the one to set the top constraint to the super view a not to the safe zone as I was doing, but I don't know why this behavior happens with the safe zone, thanks for the help @Mr.Ahtazaz

Comment: Sounds great... Good job...

Comment: I don't know why this Extra space is showing at your side. As it's strange. I have TEST same scenario(like Tab Bar Controller -> Navigational Controller -> View Controller(COLLECTION-VIEW as a subView of this View Controller HERE I'm not used COLLECTION-VIEW-CONTROLLER)  And hook up the Collection-View Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraint to SAFE AREA) But I didn't get any Extra Space on Top of the Collection View with/without Scrolling...

Comment: I have made a repo with an example in the storyboard I have two navigation for each case, the default is the one the stranger behavior, with the top constraint to the safe area  and the second constraint to the super view if you have a time check it out! https://github.com/alexpcol/collectionView-scrollBug @Mr.Ahtazaz

Comment: Ok, let me check your Code...

Comment: Hi @Chila, Are you there?

Comment: yep here I am .

Comment: Brother i have just tried your code... and in both cases it works fine... Can yu come to Skype?

Comment: can't today, on Thursday would be great

Comment: ok np...........

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me the first method setting the top constraint to the superview an not to the safe area "Please take a look at this... i Hope this helps... [uicollectionview remove top padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023384/uicollectionview-remove-top-padding)"

Thanks for your help [Mr Ahtazaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815528/mr-ahtazaz)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
first drag and drop a view controller ,
then embed it into navigation controller,
then drag and drop a collection view to the view controller
select the collection view at the bottom there is "add new constraint" click on that and uncheck constraint to margin then give zero to all the four boxes and make sure the red line is highlighted( making sure all the constraints are sets)
click on add constraint now you can rightclick and drag from tabbar to view controller and set it as viewcontrollers